# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "и" в сложноподчиненном предложении с союзом "пока"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Олег подождал, пока мама выйдет из кухни(,) и схватил телефон.*

В некоторых книгах замечал, что запятая в таких конструкциях ставилась только перед союзом "пока".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Олег подождал, **пока мама выйдет из кухни**, и схватил телефон.*

Это СПП с придаточным времени, ПОКА — временной союз. Союз И соединяет однородные сказуемые: подождал и схватил.

Придаточное относится к первому сказуемому и обособляется с двух сторон.

Сравнить: *Олег подождал, пока мама выйдет из кухни и возьмет с собой телефон.* Здесь однородные сказуемые входят в придаточное предложение, нет запятой.